# Problem with variation of calculus for noether

Tags: calculus, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

In the variational calculus, we discuss general case variation where endpoints vary as well. (i.e $x_0$ and $x_1$ vary as well). By using some calculations, we end up with:

$\delta J = \left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\delta y + (F - y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'})\delta x\right]_{x=x_0}^{x=x_1}$

Note that $\delta J$ is already a first order variation and it doesn't include euler lagrange, because assuming $y(x)$ is a true path, even doing the variation with fixed endpoints must cause $\delta J$ to be 0, so that euler lagrange part vanishes. Also, keep in mind that since $y(x)$ is a true path, $\delta J = 0$.

Question:

in the following [book](http://users.uoa.gr/%7Epjioannou/mech2/READING/Gelfand_Fomin_Calculus_of_Variations.pdf),  author uses transformation(I won't include them here as it's short and can be seen on the link in a clearer way) and here is what's important. For sure, he replaces $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ by the transformations. Important thing though, is that he only makes $\delta J$ be 0 if and only if functionals are invariant.

**My question is the following: Why can he only make $\delta J=0$ only in the case when functionals are invariant ? When you have a functional $J[y]$, you assume that $y(x)$ is a true path and then using transformation on the true path is the same thing as varying the path which should cause first order variation to be 0.**

Comment: Can you include the pages of the book that you are refering too? It would make it easier to understand exactly what your saying. But If I try to interpret what your saying varying the true path in general and transforming the true path along an invariant of the functional are not the same. One is transforming the true path and the other is effectively changing the cordinate system of the true path in every point along the true path. So I think you may be confused.